# javascript tool for coding standards

Tags: javascript, coding-style, automation, rubymine

Im looking for a tool which ideally i could integrate into rubymine (but command line is fine as well) which will warn me when I'm coding javascript against certain coding standards. The tool should be able to allow me to add additional rules so that I can do things like warn the programmer when they are using certain methods in the framework which are not recommended etc

anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at JsLint?

[JSLint,The JavaScript Code Quality Tool](http://www.jslint.com/)

There are command line tools available, but it's also possible to integrate it in your ide.

http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm

Comment: I'm currently using a variation on that (jshint) but couldn't see any easy way to add additional rules to it. Are there any tutorials for adding your own jslint rules?

Comment: Don't know any tutorials, but you can modify the source (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint). It isn't an easy way, but it is possible.